# What does 선율적인 exactly mean?

Tags: vocabulary, translation, word-usage

I want to add the word *melodious* to a phrase which altogether means **'songs that are melodious'**
So is it right if i use the word 선율적인 with 노래 or 가곡

I want to know the exact English translation of 선율적인 so that i can use it with the word 'song'

Comment: please add more context for you phrase if the answer by jick does not answer your question

Comment: You can’t get an 'exact' English translation to any expression written in Korean. There’s no drop-in replacement for anything when translating Korean to English and vice versa. `선율적인` does not exactly translate to any English vocabulary. But I can say that the English word that has the closest meaning possible to `선율적인` is `melodious`. By grammar it is correct to write `선율적인 노래` which can mean `melodious songs` in English, though it sounds strange to Korean speakers because  `선율적인` feels way too formal. For `melodious songs` I’d rather say `감미로운 노래`.

Answer (score 1):

선율적 is 선율(melody) + suffix -적, so it would mean "related to/pertaining to melodies" (as opposed to, say, harmonies or lyrics).  Unless you're a musicologist or a musical critic, that's not a word you would use often.

I'm not sure I understand the context, but if by "ladies" you mean young women, I guess 아가씨들의 선율 would be OK.  Or even 아가씨들의 노래, assuming it's a song.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my query. I understand what you mean but can you tell me the translation of 'Melodious Songs' in a female context. I think that would be the exact/ precise answer to my question.

Comment: @smsht_ccl I’m sorry, but that is not the precise answer to your question which reads `What does 선율적인 exactly mean?` and is answered by jick. Please update your question so people can actually know what you’re querying for.

Comment: @smsht_ccl I'm sorry but your edit doesn't make it any clearer what you're asking or why this answer does not answer your question. What is the context for that phrase? Is it a title of an article or part of a sentence in a longer article? If so please add more sentences showing what it's trying to say. If it's literally "songs sung by women" can you please explain this doesn't answer you question? Are you trying to find a word that stresses that the song is "melodious"?